# Erro "Out of memory (allocated 248512512)" no wp-db.php

Tags: php, wordpress

Alguem sabe qual erro estaria relacionado a essa mensagem do wordpress.

Fatal error: Out of memory (allocated 248512512) (tried to allocate 17498497 bytes) in /backup/public_html/wp-includes/wp-db.php on line 1094

Não estou conseguindo instalar plugins, ativa os que eu tenho instalado e quando tento atualiza algum artigo tambem recebo essa mensagem.

Na linha 1094 existe esse codigo

```
      /**
 * Real escape, using mysqli_real_escape_string() or mysql_real_escape_string()
 *
 * @see mysqli_real_escape_string()
 * @see mysql_real_escape_string()
 * @since 2.8.0
 * @access private
 *
 * @param  string $string to escape
 * @return string escaped
 */
function _real_escape( $string ) {
    if ( $this->dbh ) {
        if ( $this->use_mysqli ) {
            return mysqli_real_escape_string( $this->dbh, $string );
        } else {
            return mysql_real_escape_string( $string, $this->dbh );
        }
    }

    $class = get_class( $this );
    if ( function_exists( '__' ) ) {
        _doing_it_wrong( $class, sprintf( __( '%s must set a database connection for use with escaping.' ), $class ), E_USER_NOTICE );
    } else {
        _doing_it_wrong( $class, sprintf( '%s must set a database connection for use with escaping.', $class ), E_USER_NOTICE );
    }
    return addslashes( $string );
}
```

Comment: Coloque parte do código de `wp-db.php`. aparentemente ele executando uma instrução que consome toda a memoria disponivel.

Comment: Como eu arrumo isso?  poderia me ajuda

Comment: Qual versão do wp vc usa?

Comment: Eu atualizei para a ultima versão. desde então esse erro começou a aparece

Comment: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/85642/erro-wordpress-painel-admin-n%c3%a3o-entra#comment172555_85642

Comment: Amigo por favor nao duplique a pergunta, voce duplicou ela 2 vezes, isto nao vai lhe ajudar a conseguir a resposta mais rapido. Se nao conseguiu a resposta desejada tente editar a pergunta e adicionar mais detalhes e sempre use titulos mais intuitivos. Recomendo que leia este link: http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/a/3969/3635 - Boa sorte!

Answer (score 1):

Olá,
256MB é muita de memória para um script, por isso, se você estiver excedendo, as primeiras coisas para verificar se há alguns cenários:
Um loop infinito que esta escotando o seu limite de memória.
Outra coisa... Se você está puxando os dados de um banco de dados e sem querer esta puxando de uma tabela com uma grande quantidade de dados. Isso pode esgotar sua memória.
Entre outras coisas...
Como sumir com essa mensagem?!
Modificar seu `php.ini` para aumentar sua `memory_limit` para algo maior do que o que você tem atualmente para - 512MB.
Mas isso vai resolver seu problema parcialmente, provavelmente no futuro você pode ter outro problema desse, então aconselho você tentar achar o que pode esta te dando esse problema, blz?
Espero ter te ajudado.
Até mais.