# Erro de "Out of memory" ao adicionar um novo plugin

Tags: php, wordpress, include

Depois que atualizei o wordpress para a última versão não está sendo possível instalar plugins, adiciona novos artigos ou edita artigos.

Qualquer ação que faça aparece essa mensagem.

```
Fatal error: Out of memory (allocated 247726080) (tried to allocate 17615693 bytes) in /backup/public_html/teste/wp-includes/wp-db.php on line 1094
```

Comment: Ele não quer saber como encontrar o erro de Fatal error. Não é duplicata.

Comment: @Lollipop independente disto a outra pergunta provavelmente por usar a tag wordpress ja complementaria como sendo sim uma duplicata, ja que e devido a um plugin que esta acontecendo isto.

Comment: Eu desativei todos os plugins  renomeando as pastas pelo Cpainel. mas antes quando eu desativava um plugin a mensagem sumia dessa vez mesmo desativando o plugin a mensagem não desaparece

Comment: @Lollipop recomendo que mantenha a conversa ou resposta aqui: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/85638/erro-out-of-memory-allocated-248512512-no-wp-db-php devido a esta pergunta ter mais detalhes sobre o codigo.

Answer (score 0):

### Faça o seguinte:

Crie um arquivo `php.ini` e insira dentro da pasta **wp-admin** com esses códigos:

```
max_input_vars = 9000
upload_max_filesize = 8M
session.cache_limiter = public
memory_limit = QTDE_MEMORIA_PONHA;
```

No **`wp-config:`** `define('WP_MEMORY_LIMIT', '64M');`

[FONTE](http://wpmidia.com.br/tutoriais/4-formas-de-aumentar-limite-de-memoria-php-wordpress/)

Comment: Coloquei o arquivo  na pasta que disse e não adiantou

Comment: Quando essa mensagem aparecia, eu desinstalava um plugin e ela sumia,mas aparecia outra vez, agora eu desinstalei todos os plugins mas continua mostrando essa mensagem.

Comment: Editei. Esqueci de colocar o memory_limit .

Comment: No arquivo wp-config já existe esse codigo: define('WP_MEMORY_LIMIT', '64M');

Comment: nesse codigo  max_input_vars = 9000
upload_max_filesize = 8M
session.cache_limiter = public
memory_limit = QTDE_MEMORIA_PONHA;  quanto de memoria deve ser colocado em QTDE_MEMORIA_PONHA;

Comment: Ponha `64M`.............

Comment: http://wpmidia.com.br/tutoriais/4-formas-de-aumentar-limite-de-memoria-php-wordpress/